# C# Image attachment isn't shown inline on redemption

Tags: c#, email, outlook-redemption

I use the following code to add an image to an RDOMessage and try to show this image inside the HTMLBody...

```
_message.BodyFormat = 2;
_message.HTMLBody = MailHelper.GetHtmlMessage(MailBody, "utf-8");

if (ImageSource != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImageName))
{
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ImageSource));
    string id = "qr-code.png";
    int index = _message.HTMLBody.IndexOf("%imageQr%");
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        string tempDir = TempDirectory.Create();
        string tmpFile = Path.Combine(tempDir, id);
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
                    
        RDOAttachment attachment = _message.Attachments.Add(tmpFile, 1, null, ImageNage);
        attachment.ContentID = id;
        _message.HTMLBody = _message.HTMLBody.Insert(index, $"<img src=\"cid:{id}\">");
        _message.HTMLBody = _message.HTMLBody.Replace("%imageQr%", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

But the only thing I see in the message is this:
[image: Screenshot]

So the question is: What is not correct? (before and after the image are each three underlines, that is not the problem ;)) I used it in a slightly different version with the OOM version and that worked well...
Interesting to note is here, that with the OOM I could specify the `id` as a `Guid` without file name ending (i.e. without a .png), if I did that here with RDO the attachment itself was also not able to open...

---

Edit: When I send the email it arrives more or less correctly with this body tag:

```
<body lang=DE link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style='word-wrap:break-word'>
    <div class=WordSection1>
        <p>
             ___<img width=32 height=32 style='width:.3333in;height:.3333in' id="_x0000_i1025" src="cid:8b2b3585-c611-4562-884c-915fc9f9b759">___
           <o:p>
           </o:p>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

But the size is not correct and I didn't set it explicitly, also the style is not set by me...

What it should look like is this (and it does with OOM):

______

The image has 100x100 px, so the second would be correct...

But what even more is disturbing is, that it looks like below when I havn't send it yet. The user would think that the image is broken. (And I don't know how to see the HTML of a not sent email).

If I save the message and open it again it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot2]

Shortly before I send the message the HTMLBody looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>___<img src=\"cid:ab0c3c9a-9a9f-4fe7-a8e6-45c0735473a6\">___</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

And BodyFormat is 2, so it should be used as HTML, shouldn't it? So, why does it not arrive at Outlook like this?

Comment: Why not use a proper email library instead of using an external application like Outlook? .NET Framework came with SmtpClient out of the box in 2002 but even Microsoft nowadays [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-8.0#remarks) using [Mailkit](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm). All the examples in the linked page show how to create an HTML message with an embedded image

Comment: Are you using Outlook because you want to sed a message to Exchange Server? Exchange Server supports SMTP too. For advanced scenarios you can use its Web APIs. There's no need for Outlook at all

Comment: We use that too, but we have some customers that WANT to use Outlook, mostly because they want to look in the "Sent"-Folder and see if the mail was sent, what was sent and most WHEN was it sent. With SMTP you don't have a user-side log.

Comment: If you look at the HTML body after the message was created, does the `img` tag look right? Where does the message come from? Was it already being displayed by Outlook when your code is running?

Comment: Do you see the correct value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTEND_ID` in OutlookSpy (click IMessage | GetAttachmentTable | double click on the attachment)?

Comment: `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W` value is `9d9b6bbd-2f7a-48b5-a5fd-939c2da11b0f` and the `HTML`-Tag is `<img src="cid:9d9b6bbd-2f7a-48b5-a5fd-939c2da11b0f">`

Comment: Maybe it is the kind of RDOMail initialization? I initialize it like this: `RDOSession session = new RDOSession(); session.Logon(); RDOFolder folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox); _message = folder.Items.Add(rdoItemType.olMailItem);`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Any more ideas? Or maybe do you got a working C# example? On your page all examples are only snippets and in VB and I don't really understand VB.

Comment: Can you save the message as an MSG file, zip it (important!) and send it to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Dmitry Streblechenko (thanks) I found the answer:

After adding the ID to the attachment I had to save the attachment explicitly. So adding a simple:

```
attachment.Save();
```

after

```
attachment.ContentID = id;
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The cid should go inside the quotes:

```cs
mMessage.HTMLBody = _message.HTMLBody.Insert(index, $"<img src=\"cid:{id}\">";);
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But that is, sadly, not the solution. I found another solution to another problem where it was used without any quotes. So I tried deleting it and just replaced them by memory and THAT was an error, but not the error that made me posting this question at all. I will correct that in my question.